# +1 day for all cells in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of dates in a column, all of which need to be incremented by one day. What would be the best way to approach this? I have added a column with the variable 1 next to the rows with the dates, however the autofill overites the data of the other rows.

[image: I have attempted the following method, however instead of continuing the trend, the autofill overites the data of the other rows]

Comment: `=A2+1` in B2 and copy down